# How to improve running time of my binary search code in peripherical parts?

Tags: algorithm, performance, python-3.x, binary-search, divide-and-conquer

I am studying for this great Coursera course https://www.coursera.org/learn/algorithmic-toolbox . On the fourth week, we have an assignment related to binary trees.

[image]

I think I did a good job. I created a binary search code that solves this problem using recursion in Python3. That's my code:

```
#python3

data_in_sequence = list(map(int,(input().split())))

data_in_keys = list(map(int,(input()).split()))

original_array = data_in_sequence[1:]

data_in_sequence = data_in_sequence[1:]

data_in_keys = data_in_keys[1:]

def binary_search(data_in_sequence,target):

    answer = 0

    sub_array = data_in_sequence

    #print("sub_array",sub_array)

    if not sub_array:   
    #   print("sub_array",sub_array)
        answer = -1
        return answer

    #print("target",target)

    mid_point_index = (len(sub_array)//2)
    #print("mid_point", sub_array[mid_point_index])

    beg_point_index = 0
    #print("beg_point_index",beg_point_index)

    end_point_index = len(sub_array)-1
    #print("end_point_index",end_point_index)

    if sub_array[mid_point_index]==target:
        #print ("final midpoint, ", sub_array[mid_point_index])
        #print ("original_array",original_array)
        #print("sub_array[mid_point_index]",sub_array[mid_point_index])
        #print ("answer",answer)
        answer = original_array.index(sub_array[mid_point_index])

        return answer

    elif target>sub_array[mid_point_index]:
        #print("target num higher than current midpoint")
        beg_point_index = mid_point_index+1
        sub_array=sub_array[beg_point_index:]
        end_point_index = len(sub_array)-1
        #print("sub_array",sub_array)
        return binary_search(sub_array,target)

    elif target<sub_array[mid_point_index]:
        #print("target num smaller than current midpoint")
        sub_array = sub_array[:mid_point_index]
        return  binary_search(sub_array,target)

    else:
        return None

def bin_search_over_seq(data_in_sequence,data_in_keys):

    final_output = ""

    for key in data_in_keys:

        final_output = final_output + " " + str(binary_search(data_in_sequence,key))

    return final_output

print (bin_search_over_seq(data_in_sequence,data_in_keys))
```

I usually get the correct output. For instance, if I input:

```
5 1 5 8 12 13
5 8 1 23 1 11
```

I get the correct indexes of the sequences or (-1) if the term is not in sequence (first line):

```
2 0 -1 0 -1
```

However, my code does not pass on the expected running time.

```
Failed case #4/22: time limit exceeded (Time used: 13.47/10.00, memory used: 36696064/536870912.)
```

I think this happens not due to the implementation of my binary search (I think it is right). Actually, I think this happens due to some inneficieny in a peripheral part of the code. Like the way I am managing to output the final answer. However, the way I am presenting the final answer does not seem to be really "heavy"... I am lost.

Am I not seeing something? Is there another inefficiency I am not seeing? How can I solve this? Just trying to present the final result in a faster way?

Comment: recursion is going to be slow in Python... you could avoid that. Or if you are going to do that, work with only the indices and stop passing slices (which create copies) as subarrays. that being said, this sort of thing is bad: `original_array.index(sub_array[mid_point_index])`. You should already have the index. The `.index` method is simply linear search. And you are relying on global variables, which will be expensive to resolve in python: try to work with only local variables. Finally, at the beginning, you are repeating yourself a lot: `data_in_keys[1:]`. You only need to do that once.

Comment: Also, yes, the way you are aggregating your data at the end is slow. You are building up a string in a loop using `+`, which *recreates the entire string each iteration*. Instead, you can do somthing like `temp = [str(binary_search(data_in_sequence,key)) for key in data_in_keys]` then simply `return " ".join(temp)`

Comment: I mean, you realize that `original_array.index(sub_array[mid_point_index])` defeats the *whole purpose* of binary search. If you are going to use `.index`, you might as well just do `original_array.index(key)` ... So yeah, just re-implement this *in terms of the indices* from the beginning.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga nice, thanks. Actually, I need to use the divide and conquer method for this problem. Does this means that I need to use recursion (that's why I used it)? What other alternative do I have? Trying an iterative approach?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, yeah, you are right. I actually did not realize this until now.

Comment: I understand that you need to use binary search. But honestly, I doubt they'd assume you would convert the recursion to an iterative solution, they probably benchmarked based on a recursive solution (since that is likely what they lectured on). Really, the other issues I brought up are more likely the culprit. Stop making slices, use indices from the beginning. And *don't use `.index` method!*, don't build up a string in a loop using `+` ...

Comment: So, check out the high-level algorithm on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm#Procedure). You'll notice it is all in terms of *indices*. Taking slices, which create copies, at each stop will definitely slow you down.

Comment: Anyway, you can basically directly translate that algorithm in the wikipedia quote into Python. Your function header, if you are going to use recursion, should be something like `def binary_search(arr, T, L, R):` where `arr` is your array, `T` is your target, `L` and `R` are the left and right indices. When you start the search, you manually pass `binary_search(arr, <some_target>, 0, len(arr) - 1)`. You *could* use recursion, but actually, you could just use a loop!

Comment: In addition to all suggestions by @juanpa.arrivillaga, I would say that instead of reading targets into memory, you could just do `for key in list(map(int,(input()).split()))[1:]: print(binary_search(data, key), end=' ')` thus avoiding any final aggregation of data.

Comment: If I got it right (Python is not my cup of tea) then you call `k` times bin search on `a[n]` which is `O(k.n.log(n))` Why not index sort `b[k]` array `O(k.log(k))` time and `O(k)` space. Then just scan linearly once `O(max(k,n))` (similar to merging 2 sorted lists) no bin search needed .... as `k,n` limits are the same if we assume `n=k`  the whole thing would be `O(n.log(n))` opposing to yours `O(n.n.log(n))`